# How to get data related to sets of different combinations dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, informix

I want to get data related to sets of different combinations.

EX :

If I have table: `EmployeeLocation`

```
empNum  locationId  extensionId  year

 534      CX1         AX         2015
 534      LM1         RQ         2015
 677      LM1         ST         2015
```

---

Res : `534,2015`

Now I want to query all employees who were in Location (`CX1 AND LM1`) both of them in `2015`. Maybe I change the combination to (`CX1 AND LM1 AND LR3`)… etc.

---

How to make something like that to be dynamic combination. According to user input for set of location combination.

Comment: @IvanStoev `Contains` = `IN` and this's not what i want , i want `CX1 AND LM1` for example

Comment: I am not sure what the question is asking...Is this looking for a dynamic query?

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare Yeah, I realized that right after posting the comment, that's why the comment was removed. What ORM are you using - EF or ?

Comment: @IvanStoev : For this part ,no `ORM` just `ado.net` ,so if i could do it through `sql query` or `LINQ` it will be acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach that you can use with Linq is the following.

Suppose you have a class as follows:

```
private class EmployeeLocation {
    public int EmpNum {get; set;} 
    public string LocationId {get; set;}
    public string ExtensionId {get; set;}
    public int Year {get; set;} 
}
```

You can create a method that will handle the search based on the parameters provided in input:

```
public IEnumerable<EmployeeLocation> Search(
    int[] empNumArray, 
    string[] locationIdArray, 
    string[] extensionIdArray, 
    int[] yearArray){

    IEnumerable<EmployeeLocation> result = EmployeeLocationList;
    if (empNumArray != null){
        foreach(var empNum in empNumArray){
            result = result.Where(r => r.EmpNum == empNum);
        }
    }
    if (locationIdArray != null){
        foreach(var locationId in locationIdArray){
            result = result.Where(r => r.LocationId);
        }
    }
    if (extensionIdArray != null){
        foreach(var extensionId in extensionIdArray){
            result = result.Where(r => r.ExtensionId == extensionId);
        }
    }
    if (yearArray != null){
        foreach(var year in yearArray ){
            result = result.Where(r => r.Year == year);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Contains = in and i don't want (or) i want (and)

Comment: One and the same value (e.g. `r.LocationId`) cannot be equal to several other values (what your array loops produce), so the result will always be empty.

Answer (score 1):

How about checking each condition and then taking the intersection of the results?

```
    public IEnumerable<int> Search(IEnumerable<Employee> employees, IEnumerable<Condition> conditions) {
        var subresults = new List<IEnumerable<int>>();
        IEnumerable<int> result = null;
        foreach (var condition in conditions) {
            subresults.add(employees.Where(e => e.CheckCondition(condition)).Select(e => e.EmpNum));
        }
        foreach (var subresult in subresults) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = subresult;
            } else {
                result = result.Intersect(subresult)
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
     locationId VARCHAR(3);
     year INTEGER;

BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE    

    'SELECT empNum FROM EmployeeLocation
     WHERE locationId = CX1 AND locationId = LM1 AND year = 2015';
END;
```

This might be a simplistic way to describe the query. I think the rest that is needed is an event handler to specify which `locationId` to use.

Here is more detailed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE empNum(locId VARCHAR(3), yr VARCHAR(4)) IS
   TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
   c cur_typ;
   locationId VARCHAR(3);
   year INTEGER;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE    

    'SELECT empNum FROM EmployeeLocation
     WHERE locationId = locId AND locationId = locId AND year = yr';
END;
```

I think using cur_type as reference cursor could be used for a query string.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm